# Unable to resolve with Autofac after upgrading to .NET 4.6.1

Tags: dependency-injection, autofac, thinktecture-ident-server, .net-4.6.1

I already posted a question about this on [GitHub](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/706) and was advised to put it on StackOverflow:

I'm having problem with ThinkTecture Authorization Server since updating to .NET 4.6.1. As some people know, AuthorizationServer uses AutoFac (and we've updated that as well to Autofac 3.5.2).

The weird thing is that everything is OK on my local machine and in our DEV-environment, but it fails on INT! (all these environments contain .NET 4.6.1):

The problem we're having starts right at the beginning and looks like this:

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
>      IsIT.SignonServices.Common.Logger..ctor() in c:\Builds\23\48\src\IsIT.SignonServices.Common\Logger\Logger.cs:43
>      lambda_method(Closure , Object[] ) +140
>      Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate() +271
>
> [DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(Thinktecture.AuthorizationServer.Interfaces.IAuthorizationServerConfiguration)' on type 'TokenService'. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (See inner exception for details.)]
>      Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate() +736
>      Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +266
>      Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) +86
>      Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() +62
>      Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +170
>      Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate() +124
>      Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +266
>      Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) +86
>      Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() +62
>      Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +170
>      Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +109
>      Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance) +122
>      Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptionalService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +70
>      Autofac.Integration.Mvc.AutofacDependencyResolver.GetService(Type serviceType) +95
>      System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +59
>
> [InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'Thinktecture.AuthorizationServer.OAuth2.AuthorizeController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
>      System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +240
>      System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +103
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +268
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +95
>      System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +921
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +137

Can somebody please help, I think it has something to do with reflection/injection-resolving?

Comment: do you have the .net framework 4.6.* installed on the INT enviornment?

Comment: Yes, as I clearly stated I have 4.6.1 installed on all environments. Update: I was able to fix the problem by lazy loading one of the component, so it got loaded later in the pipeline, before the Autofac would kick in, and was trying to initialize it's config and types :-)